# Why is the weak limit of the derivatives the derivative of the weak limit here?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

In [1, chapter 8.2.1.b, p.466] the author uses the following argument:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open, bounded domain with smooth boundary. Given a bounded sequence $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $W^{1,q}(U)$ there exists a weakly convergent subsequence $(u_{k_j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a function $u \in W^{1,q}(U)$ such that \begin{equation} \begin{cases} u_{k_j} \rightharpoonup u & \text{weakly in } L^q (U) \\ Du_{k_j} \rightharpoonup Du & \text{weakly in } L^q (U,\mathbb{R}^N) \end{cases} \end{equation}

---

My question is: how can he infer this rather than

\begin{equation} \begin{cases} u_{k_j} \rightharpoonup u & \text{weakly in } L^q (U) \\ Du_{k_j} \rightharpoonup Df & \text{weakly in } L^q (U,\mathbb{R}^N) ,\end{cases} \end{equation} where not necessarily $f=u$?

> I.e. how can he infer that the weak limit of the derivatives is the derivative of the weak limit?

---

[1] Evans, L. C.: Partial differential equations, Nr. 19 in Graduate
Studies in Mathematics. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI,
2nd edition, 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because taking the weak derivative is a bounded linear operation, hence weakly continuous.

You can also prove it directly:
if $u_k$ converges weakly towards $u$ and $Du_k$ converges weakly towards $Df$, then
$$
\int Df \, \phi
\leftarrow
\int Du_k \, \phi
=
-\int u_k \, D\phi
\to
-\int u \, D \phi
=
\int Du \, \phi
$$
for all $\phi \in C_0^\infty(U)$.

Comment: I assume that by `\ot` you meant a left arrow, in this case meaning that the item on the left is the limit of what is on the right. I edited your answer accordingly. Also, I should point out that taking the weak derivative is bounded from $W^{1,q}$ into $L^q$, not into $W^{1,q}$ (which I am sure you know, but some readers may be confused by your phrasing).

Comment: One more comment: Weak convergence $u_k\rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,k}$ is *defined* as $u_k\rightharpoonup u$ and $Du_k\rightharpoonup Du$ in $L^q$. But the argument given here shows that if $Du_k$ couldn't possibly converge weakly to anything else.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Thanks for your edit, math was not rendering. One comment on weak convergence: I would not define weak convergence in $W^{1,k}$ via weak convergence of the function and its derivatives in $L^k$, but rather use the usual definition of weak convergence.